# cannot change the value of base class variable from derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Hello I'm a bit confused of this problem I'm currently practicing to enhance my Inheritance task in c++. Would you mine to help me.

My goal is to update the acct_balance variable which is from base class.

```
    #include <iostream>

class Account{
    public:
    Account(double initial_balance)
    {
        if(initial_balance >= 0)
            acct_balance = initial_balance;
        else
            std::cout << "Invalid Balance!" << std::endl;
    }
    void credit(double x)
    {
        acct_balance += x;
    }
    void debit(double x)
    {   
        if(x <= acct_balance){
            acct_balance -= x;
            flagWidraw = true;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Debit amount exceeded account balance." << std::endl; 
    }
    double getBalance()
    {
        return acct_balance;
    }
    public:
    double acct_balance;
    bool flagWidraw = false;
};

class SavingsAccount:public Account{
    public:
        double interest_rate;
        SavingsAccount(double balance, double interest):Account(balance)
        {
            interest_rate = interest;
        }
    double calculateInterest (){
        return (acct_balance * (interest_rate/100));
    }
};

class CheckingAccount:public Account{
    public:
        double charged_fee;
        CheckingAccount(double balance, double fee):Account(balance)
        {
            charged_fee = fee;
        }
    void credit()
    {
        acct_balance -= charged_fee;
        std::cout << "Checking Account Credit deduction fee "<< Account::acct_balance << std::endl;
    }
    void debit()
    {
        if(flagWidraw == true)
            acct_balance -= charged_fee;

        std::cout << "Checking Account Debit deduction fee "<< acct_balance << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Account a(500.00);
    SavingsAccount sa(a.getBalance(),12); //fixed interest rate 12
    double interest = sa.calculateInterest();
    std::cout << "Interest amount is added to your credit: " << interest << std::endl;
    a.credit(interest);

    CheckingAccount ca(a.getBalance(), 30);
    ca.credit();

    std::cout << "Balance is: " << a.getBalance() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And your problem is..?

Comment: You have three different objects (`a`, `sa` and `ca`) that are totally unrelated to each other. Operations on one object will not automatically happen on any of the other objects.

Comment: the `acct_balance` variable is not updating values even though I called credit function from `CheckingAccount` Class

Comment: I'm really new to the language, probably the best solutions is using pointers?

Comment: No need for pointers. In modern C++ pointers are rarely needed. Instead you need to create *one* object and perform operations on that single object only. Why do you think operations on e.g. `ca` would make things happen in the object `a`? Those are two different objects without any real relationship. In other words, try printing the result of `ca.getBalance()` instead.

Comment: Yes I already tried running it now. Thanks!